# Low Side Overcurrent Detection with Adjustable Maximum - Difference amplifier or non-inverting amplifier?

Tags: current, h-bridge, protection

Situation:

- H-bridge circuit with mosfets.
- A low-side shunt resistor is used to measure the overall current.
- The selected bridge driver IC is equipped with an overcurrent
  protection feature.  This is implemented as an input pin (ITRIP)
  connected to an internal comparator. The overcurrent protection is
  triggered whenever a voltage of 0.5 V or higher in reference to the
  IC ground is applied to the input pin.
- The IC ground is slightly decoupled  from the main power
  ground with an inductor.
- A trimmer potentiometer should be used to adjust the current limit.

The first idea here was to use a single non-inverting op amp circuit (below).

However I am unsure if the two different grounds can cause problems here?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmnS6M.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The second idea then was to combine a difference amplifier
with fixed resistors and the non-inverting op amp circuit (to allow for adjustable gain):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyF2F6.png)</sup>

Is this superior to the first version at all?

What solution would you recommend or consider best suitable for this situation?
(Best in terms of reliability,  low cost and low amount of separate components)

Thank you very much!

**Update:**
Based on @Daniel s suggestion:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fchVA9.png)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

As a first-look/first-try, I would make a comparator circuit on the power ground side, make it trimable however you like, then output a digital output into Itrip. That way you've got 0.5V to play with and don't have to worry about minuscule ground differentials creating noise in your trip point.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel , I am not sure if I fully understood it yet, so I  added another schematic to my question. Could you please take a look at it?

Comment: Looks pretty good! You just need to create yourself a little precision voltage reference and decouple it to the power ground near where you're sensing.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Daniel, I would not cross the power boundary except with a status signal.

I would probably use a [part](http://www.linear.com/parametric/Current_Sense_Amplifiers) [designed](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/amplifiers-linear/current-sense-amplifiers-overview.page) [for](http://www.analog.com/en/products/amplifiers/specialty-amplifiers/current-sense-amplifiers.html) [the job](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/amplifiers/current-sense-amplifiers.html).

The nice thing about these is they have been specifically designed to sense high or low side (depending on part) without having to do special things to work around common mode range issues to be able to achieve the task.